# Topic not created in PubSub Emulator

Tags: java, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I an trying Google PubSub Java Client library with Google PubSub Emulator.

I am running the PubSub Emulator as a docker container.

I can access the Emulator from my local machine using url like

`http://localhost:32805/v1/projects/<DUMMY_PROJECT_ID>/topics`

`http://localhost:32805/v1/projects/<DUMMY_PROJECT_ID>/subscriptions`

Have created a topic using

`http://localhost:32805/v1/projects/<DUMMY_PROJECT_ID>/topics/<DUMMY_TOPIC_NAME>`

a subscription using

`http://localhost:32805/v1/projects/<DUMMY_PROJECT_ID>/subscriptions/<DUMMY_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME>`

can push msgs using

`http://localhost:32805/v1/projects/<DUMMY_PROJECT_ID>/topics/<DUMMY_TOPIC_NAME>:publish`

can pull msgs using

`http://localhost:32805/v1/projects/<DUMMY_PROJECT_ID>/subscriptions/<DUMMY_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME>:pull`

Java application is also running as a separate docker container and has following env vars set...

```
PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST --- localhost:32805

PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID --- <DUMMY_PROJECT_ID>
```

and the following code...

```
    String hostport = System.getenv("PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST");

    ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(hostport).usePlaintext().build();

    try {
        TransportChannelProvider channelProvider = FixedTransportChannelProvider
                .create(GrpcTransportChannel.create(channel));

        CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = NoCredentialsProvider.create();

        // Set the channel and credentials provider when creating a `TopicAdminClient`.
        // Similarly for SubscriptionAdminClient
        TopicAdminClient topicClient = TopicAdminClient.create(TopicAdminSettings.newBuilder()
                .setTransportChannelProvider(channelProvider).setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build());

        TopicName topicName = TopicName.of(projectID, "niks-test-01");

        topicClient.createTopic(topicName);

        // Set the channel and credentials provider when creating a `Publisher`.
        // Similarly for Subscriber
        Publisher publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).setChannelProvider(channelProvider)
                .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        channel.shutdown();
    }
```

Application is up and the above code also executes successfully but when I query the topic
using `http://localhost:32805/v1/projects/<DUMMY_PROJECT_ID>/topics` it returns nothing...

After printing lot of logs I see that app is stuck @ `topicClient.createTopic(topicName);` no further logs or exceptions...

Any idea whats wrong here... Thanks...

**Edit#1**: Found that it is less of an emulator issue but more of a docker issue... Containers r not able to talk using localhost...

Comment: I am assuming that you must be the document [1](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator#pubsub-emulator-java), Please explain what do you mean by " running the PubSub Emulator as a docker container." , Are you running the Pub/Sub Emulator locally on your host Docker Container  or on Google Cloud ?  Can you try running the Pub/Sub Emulator other than a Docker container to rule out of any error in the container runtime environment?

Comment: With the Error message shown " app is stuck @ topicClient.createTopic(topicName) " It seems like the [Java Client library](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries)  issue , Please see the [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485473/google-pub-sub-java-examples)  that may help you solve your issue.

Comment: As i have mentioned in my **edit#1** I found this to be a docker problem and nothing to do with the implementation... Eventually I figured it out that it was a network issues... I created a docker network and mapped it all containers to it... Now containers can talk 2 each other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found during my initial investigation, it was not an application issue but more of a docker issue.

During further investigation I found that containers might not be using same network.

So I created a network with

`docker network create test-network`

and then

`docker run --network=test-network -itd --name=pubsub-emulator <IMAGE_NAME>`

&

`docker run --network=test-network -itd --name=pubsub-app <IMAGE_NAME> -e PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST=pubsub-emulator:<INTERNAL_PORT`

Now the app is able to communicate with the pubsub-emulator...

Comment: Thank you for the updates, it means your issue is resolved after fixing the network issue with Docker Containers.

Comment: @SohailAlvi yes my issue was fixed by putting all containers in a same network...